# Disabled button is still clickable

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton

I have the following piece of code. Here the button is enabled only when all 3 conditions satisfy

```
<apex:commandButton disabled="{!(AModel.InviteDisabled || AModel.VerifyDShareAttachmentType || AModel.allAInvitationResponse)}"  onclick="......" id="Share" value="Share"/>
```

The problem with this code is that, once one of the conditions gets satisfied, the Share button is still shown as disabled but it turns clickable. I am fairly new to salesforce, can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: please add your code for better response

Comment: did you rerender this button and what do you mean by `shown as disabled but it turns clickable`.  also check css may be you forgot to remove some css or styleclass.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the button in some given condition you can simply use `rendered` attribute of [apex:commandbutton](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm).
In this case there is no need of applying the css.

Although if you want to show it in disabled form you have to check that any CSS is overriding the property of button or not.From syntax perspective you are on right track.